# Number aware string sorting with comparator

Tags: java, strings, sorting

I have this class for use in sorting strings such that if strings have a number in the same position it will order the numbers in increasing order.

Alphabetical gives:

- file1
- file10
- file2

What I'm calling "number aware" string sorting should give:

- file1
- file2
- file10

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270784/how-to-split-a-string-between-letters-and-digits-or-between-digits-and-letters) is what I have using a regex split from there.

The code seems to work. Any cases where I could run into problem? If not any suggestions on making it simpler or more efficient.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class NumberAwareStringComparator implements Comparator<String>{
     public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

            String[] s1Parts = s1.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
            String[] s2Parts = s2.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

            int i = 0;
            while(i < s1Parts.length && i < s2Parts.length){

                //if parts are the same
                if(s1Parts[i].compareTo(s2Parts[i]) == 0){
                    ++i;
                }else{
                    try{

                        int intS1 = Integer.parseInt(s1Parts[i]);
                        int intS2 = Integer.parseInt(s2Parts[i]);

                        //if the parse works

                        int diff = intS1 - intS2; 
                        if(diff == 0){
                            ++i;
                        }else{
                            return diff;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        return s1.compareTo(s2);
                    }
                }//end else
            }//end while

            //Handle if one string is a prefix of the other.
            // nothing comes before something.
            if(s1.length() < s2.length()){
                return -1;
            }else if(s1.length() > s2.length()){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You want to compare digits no matter their place in the string, correct? For instance, given strings `file1img`, `file10img`, `file2img`, you want them sorted `file1img`, `file2img`, `file10img`? If so, the pattern matched in your linked answer should work. Otherwise you should compare from the ends of the strings.

Comment: Rule of thumb: `}//end while` If you need such comments to structure your code or make it more readable, there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: Bobby, Do you have any suggestions on improving the code? I think //end is entirely subjective and doesn't say anything about the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations, and should be avoided if possible.  The fundamental reason you have to deal with `NumberFormatException` is that after splitting, you don't know whether each part contains a number or a non-number.

Here's a strategy that always compares non-digits to non-digits, and numbers to numbers.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NumberAwareStringComparator implements Comparator<CharSequence> {
    public static final NumberAwareStringComparator INSTANCE =
        new NumberAwareStringComparator();

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\D*)(\\d*)");

    private NumberAwareStringComparator() {
    }

    public int compare(CharSequence s1, CharSequence s2) {
        Matcher m1 = PATTERN.matcher(s1);
        Matcher m2 = PATTERN.matcher(s2);

        // The only way find() could fail is at the end of a string
        while (m1.find() && m2.find()) {
            // matcher.group(1) fetches any non-digits captured by the
            // first parentheses in PATTERN.
            int nonDigitCompare = m1.group(1).compareTo(m2.group(1));
            if (0 != nonDigitCompare) {
                return nonDigitCompare;
            }

            // matcher.group(2) fetches any digits captured by the
            // second parentheses in PATTERN.
            if (m1.group(2).isEmpty()) {
                return m2.group(2).isEmpty() ? 0 : -1;
            } else if (m2.group(2).isEmpty()) {
                return +1;
            }

            BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger(m1.group(2));
            BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger(m2.group(2));
            int numberCompare = n1.compareTo(n2);
            if (0 != numberCompare) {
                return numberCompare;
            }
        }

        // Handle if one string is a prefix of the other.
        // Nothing comes before something.
        return m1.hitEnd() && m2.hitEnd() ? 0 :
               m1.hitEnd()                ? -1 : +1;
    }
}
```

Since strings of digits (such as those representing dates, like `20131212123456.log`) can overflow an `int`, I've used `java.math.BigInteger`.

Also, since the code works just as well with `CharSequence` as with `String`, I've generalized the type to `Comparator<CharSequence>`.

Comment: I thought that Integer.parseInt always had to be surrounded with try catch (maybe this post explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255880/why-integer-parseint-is-compiling-without-try-catch). If it does not need to be caught then I could just remove the try catch portion after the check for digits. This solution seems good though. Good idea making it effectively static with the singleton like INSTANCE.

Comment: We have log files on our systems that have the following names: 201312121444.43234.log ... you still need the NumberFormatException

Comment: In this instance (because `\\d` does not match `-`) the expression `return n1 - n2;` is 'OK', but, in general, you should never use this 'pattern' in a comparator: If `n1 = 2147483640` and `n2 = -10` we would expect to return a 'positive' value, but, in reality, n1 - n2 will overflow, and will become very negative.

Comment: @rolfl Amended to use `java.math.BigInteger`.

Comment: For my purposes negative numbers are not an issue. The numbers in file names would be run numbers from a machine so no negative. I could envision cases for scientific notation 'run_10_4e-10.dat' but I'm not sure that could be easily handled.

Comment: @200_success I think this is a good answer. If it really was **me** doing this compare, and if I thought of the regex pattern you used (which is a good one, BTW), then I also may add two checks before the BigInt work: make sure both values are same length (longer numbers are always bigger); do simple `Integer.parseInt(...)` for short values (9-digits or less)

Comment: @rolfl Actually, in GNU Classpath at least, `BigInteger` has [optimizations](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html#line.1601) for numbers that fit in an `int`.

Comment: Two questions, Can you explain the explicit calls to group(1) and group(2)? Also could you simplify the epilogue as you suggest with s1.length() - s2.length() in this solution?

Comment: Explained matcher.group() in comments. You _could_ use `return s1.length() - s2.length()` as an epilogue, but I chose to test `.hitEnd()` because it's obviously related to how the while-loop terminated, and therefore makes the code more coherent.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you can't use difference in lengths with your Match object in the loop. Good solution.

Comment: @rolfl Longer numbers are not necessarily bigger, due to the possibility of leading zeros.

Answer (score 7):

In general, I think this solutions is doing the right thing, and the algorithm, in a broad sense is doing it the right way.

There are two specific areas where I think it can be improved:

1. Regular Expressions can be compiled and reused. This compareTo method is splitting many, many strings, and it would make a big difference to reuse the patterns rather than to recompile them twice each time the method is called. So, compile the pattern and use a static reference to it:

   ```
   private static final Pattern BOUNDARYSPLIT = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
   ```

   Then, in your method you can reuse that pattern easily with:

   ```
   String[] s1Parts = BOUNDARYSPLIT.split(s1);
   String[] s2Parts = BOUNDARYSPLIT.split(s2);
   ```

   This will save a lot of performance.
2. The second issue is the 'convenience' of using a try/catch block for the ParseInt. Creating, throwing, and catching an exception is a surprisingly slow and complicated process. Using a try/catch as part of a 'routine' code-path is a mistake. Especially in something as frequent as a compareTo method. You should first make an attempt to see whether the input has a small hope of converting before throwing an exception:

   ```
   if (s1parts[i].charAt(0) >= '0' && s1parts[i].charAt(0) <= '9') {
       // put your try-catch block here....
   } else {
       return s1parts[i].compareTo(s2parts[i]);
   }
   ```
3. I noticed, while writing this up, that in your catch-block, you use:

   ```
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
   ```

   I don't think it makes a difference in the functionality, but, you should probably use:

   ```
    return s1parts[i].compareTo(s2parts[i]);
   ```

Comment: Good points. Static pattern and a check before the exception are both great points. I think that adding a check on s2parts[i] in your if statement would ensure the try never thorws the exception. If s1part[i] is numeric but s2part[i] is not a normal string compare would be fine. Thoughts?

Comment: @pbible - when I wrote my answer I worked on the assumption (which is broken, I think) that if s1parts[x] is a number then s2parts[x] is also a number (and visa-versa for string). As a result I thought I only needed to check one side to see if it was numeric. Now I see that, if the input is: "file10x" and "10filex" you will still get an exception.... so, you are right, you should have the second check.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach appears to be basically sound.

My main concern is `catch(Exception ex)`.  **Catching all exceptions** like that makes me very nervous and puzzled about your intent.  I have to wonder, what could possibly go wrong inside the try-block?  My thought process:

1. The exception would have to be thrown from the `Integer.parseInt()` calls, since the diff portion is foolproof.
2. Obviously, `Integer.parseInt()` could throw `NumberFormatException`.
3. What about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?  No, we're safe, because you already checked in the while-loop condition.  Furthermore, if `++i` got executed, it wouldn't enter the else-clause.
4. What about `NullPointerException`?  It seems impossible, since the parts arrays came from `String.split()`.
5. Anything else?  `OutOfMemoryError`, maybe?  No, that's a `Throwable` but not an `Exception`.
6. Any other possibilities?  No.  Am I sure?  No.

For my sanity, please change that to `catch (NumberFormatException ex)`!

Changing the **while-loop into a for-loop** would make it easier to recognize the flow control.  You can also save a level of indentation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s1Parts.length && i < s2Parts.length; ++i) {
    //if parts are the same
    if (s1Parts[i].compareTo(s2Parts[i]) == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    try {
        int intS1 = Integer.parseInt(s1Parts[i]);
        int intS2 = Integer.parseInt(s2Parts[i]);

        //if the parse works
        int diff = intS1 - intS2; 
        if (diff == 0) {
            // continue;    // Actually, this is a no-op
        } else {
            return diff;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // Buggy, as noted by @rolfl
        // return s1.compareTo(s2);
        return s1Parts[i].compareTo(s2Parts[i]);
    }
}
```

The **epilogue could be simplified** to just `return s1.length() - s2.length()`.

Comment: Definitely a good catch with NumberFormatException. What about the test for digits suggested by rolfl? Do you agree?

Comment: See my other answer for an alternative to testing for digits.

Comment: @200_success - good catch on the NumberFormatException vs. Exception, but I think your other answer is much better, Excpetions should never be part of **expected** (routine) program flow.

Answer (score 1):

Changes the pattern to this if you want to use decimals:

```
private static Pattern BOUNDARYSPLIT = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D\\.)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```