# Nesting versus GOTO: which is better to avoid?

Tags: java, parsing

In Java they're not really known as `GOTO` statements and are rather referred to as [Branching Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), but I find that the former term is a bit more indicative of what they actually do.

Regardless, I've been designing some code recently which has me in a bind.  On the one hand, I've been taught to avoid avid use of such statements because [they make code both non-linear and more difficult to follow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices).  They of course have excellent uses, and I'm not one of those puritans who says that they should be discarded at any cost.

On the other hand, there's also a [common tenet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928556/programming-style-should-you-return-early-if-a-guard-condition-is-not-satisfied) that says I [ought to avoid](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) deep [nesting of conditions and loops](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=1421) if it's [possible and reasonable to do so](http://debuggable.com/posts/programming-psychology-return-home-early:4811de9f-ae28-49c2-a7dc-2f154834cda3).

So here's my conundrum.  I'm hoping someone can guide me and give me some solid reasoning and best practices advice, because apparently my brain can't handle the conflicting signals.

Several times through my code, I have a `for()` loop which is something like the following (where `lines` is a `List<String>` and `values` is a `Map<String, String>`):

```
for(String line : lines) {

    if(line.charAt(0) == '#') {
        LOGGER.debug("Skipping commented line in file.");
        continue;
    }

    line = line.trim().toLowerCase();
    String[] pair = line.split("=");

    if(pair.length != 2) {
        LOGGER.error("Skipping malformed line in file: " + line);
        continue;
    }

    pair[0] = pair[0].trim();
    pair[1] = pair[1].trim();

    if(values.containsKey(pair[0])) {
        LOGGER.debug("Value is already assigned.");
        continue;
    }

    values.put(pair[0], pair[1]);

    //...and so on with still more processing
}
```

The reason I gave a little bit more in this code snippet than is strictly required to understand the use case is because I think the fact that the `for` loop isn't really "tight" and that it performs a lot of processing is relevant to the style choice.  To me, it makes the code feel somewhat sloppy and messy to have multiple areas scattered throughout it which bump the reader back to the beginning of the loop.  In other words, it feels a lot like [the good old `GOTO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) that everyone [loves to hate on](http://xkcd.com/292/).

So my other design option is to write it with the following style:

```
for(String line : lines) {
    if(!line.charAt(0) == '#') {
        line = line.trim().toLowerCase();
        String[] pair = line.split("=");
        if(pair.length == 2) {
            pair[0] = pair[0].trim();
            pair[1] = pair[1].trim();
            if(!values.containsKey(pair[0])) {
                values.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
                //...and so on with still more processing
            }
            else {
                LOGGER.debug("Value is already assigned.");
            }
        }
        else {
            LOGGER.error("Skipping malformed line in file: " + line);
        }
    }
    else {
        LOGGER.debug("Skipping commented line in file.");
    }
}
```

Both of these techniques/styles makes my eye twitch spastically for various reasons, and I keep rewriting my code to fit whichever rationalization wins out in the current moment.  I also think that if you definitively choose one as "The Style" to always go with, it's trivial to extend the above code snippets to the point where it makes more sense to go with the other.

Does anyone have a more definitive statement of when to use one style over the other?  Or even just some good reasoning to apply to a situation to make sure you are following the best rule and coding practice?  Any general tips, tricks, and advice for dealing with these sorts of situations?

Comment: In either approach, it is worth considering [Extract-Till-You-Drop](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop) (with well thought of names for your extracted methods) for the code inside your if-blocks. It is certainly a best practice and makes the final top-level function clean and readable either with early-returns (which are easier to spot in a clean + small top-level function) or even with nested-ifs.   I've rarely squirmed at either of the two approaches when the thankfully SMALL function's intent is crystal clear and reads like prose.

Comment: One way would be to create a class holding these pair values with a static factory method that does all this checking and returns `null` on failure. That would cut the checking to `for { Pair pair = Pair.fromString(line); if (pair != null) {`. Within that static factory method you can use `return`...it's basically the same, but better wrapped.

Comment: @JeffGohlke In that case, you should be using [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to accomplish the task, rather than rolling your own. It does exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @AJMansfield Meh.  No thank you.  I've seen it used in my production environment and I'm not a huge fan of it.  Writing my own allows me to handle values as something other than `String` if I want to, for example.  The `Properties` API simply doesn't seem terribly powerful or useful to me.  If others find it sufficient, though, that's great.

Comment: In any case, the question is more about how to handle issues of this *style* rather than addressing alternate ways to achieve the goal of the particular use case.

Comment: [GOTO causes velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: I misread this as **Nietzsche** vs GOTO... I was genuinely excited to find out what that meant.

Comment: I agree; both of these make me twitchy. The solution I would recommend is: take a step back and ask yourself what you are really doing.  **You are writing a parser without writing a lexer first**.  I would be inclined to structure this code much more like a traditional compiler. Define a lexical grammer. Decompose the text into a sequence of tokens. Then run a parser over the tokens to produce a data structure.

Comment: You could split the different tests into small boolean-methods and use these in you nesting. It looks a little smaller and is (depending on the programmer you're talking too) even a better (OO) programming practice

Comment: @user1167442 I really wish that was an XKCD or something now.

Comment: All control structures are just GOTO in disguises, so you should write all your methods without any control structures, no for-loops, no while-loops, no if-conditionals, and no functions. They're all just GOTO and we all know that GOTO is the vilest of all evil.

Comment: Don't use GOTO (well you can't in Java anyway).  Don't use extra flags to terminate loops.  **Do use break with labels**.

Comment: Where is the `GOTO`? `continue` (at least without a label) is not a `GOTO` in any way. It's like saying `return` is a `GOTO` and should be avoided...

Comment: Control structures are not GOTOs; they are jumps, secured behind the language. The problem with GOTOs is not the jump—that happens all the time in assembly and you really can’t avoid it—but the way they (real GOTOs) influence your code and make it vulnerable. Using control structures is more than just fine and you definitely shouldn’t see the jumps in the background—you will never be able to avoid those anyway. Instead, make sure that your code is well written and easy to read.

Comment: I'll join the camp that says: whenever you use `break` or `continue`, you should *probably* extract and use `return` instead.

Comment: "return" and "continue" are no different from each other. What's going on is you have a series of criteria which must be met before you can get to the goal (extracting a key-value pair) and you have to do an increasing amount of work to verify each criterion. If it fails at any point, then you give up on that input and proceed to the next. Look up "Arrow Antipattern".

Comment: Structured programming with go to statements (1974) by Donald E. Knuth
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.103.6084

Why Functional Programming Matters, by John Hughes
http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html

Comment: Edsger Dijkstra Considered Harmful http://se-according-to-futhork.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/edsger-dijkstra-considered-harmful.html

You should rewrite your program in Haskell, and in assembly language, and as a flow diagram.

To answer your question, it's better to avoid Java.

Comment: @poke: When an algorithm fits structured programming constructs, one should use those.  When it doesn't, a `goto` or equivalent may sometimes yield clearer code than alternatives.  One advantage of such instructions is that the target labels very concisely shout *EXECUTION MAY TRANSFER DIRECTLY HERE* and are less likely to escape notice than comments or `continue` statements within a loop.

Comment: I am surprised no-one suggested to use Exceptions as a way of exiting the handling of a line. It does look a lot like the continue, except they can all go to the same place to be logged, and you really have to do something about it.

Comment: This is a case of misunderstanding why some people consider GOTOs harmful. GOTOs are considered harmful when they obfuscate what the code is doing (i.e. the user is jumping around all over the place). Continues are a logical form of jump as they always point back to the same area - the beginning of a loop. Personally I would say the continues are far more readable than the nesting; the nesting requires the user to mentally unpick the nests first, whereas the continues are easily understandable - 'ignore the rest of the code and continue as you were'.

Comment: Of course, lambda is the ultimate GOTO.

Comment: @Pseudonym Haha, alas, I have yet to master the arcane art of lambda.

Comment: @njzk2, you're joking, of course...

Comment: @Craig : Not really. I think it is worth considering. A big try ... catch around the whole treatment, no tests at all, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain style. It accounts for case of `line == null` for instance, or any other issue in the handling of the line, without adding more tests.

Comment: @njzk2, I typically try not to be hard-line dogmatic about things, but using exceptions for flow control might be one of those things. What is wrong with using tests? If you rely on exceptions for flow control, you're just putting the tests off on someone else, then relying for normal flow control on a mechanism designed and intended for handling EXCEPTIONAL conditions. In other words, intended for handling things you can't test for. Using exceptions unavoidably harms performance of the code, as well. There are **many** reasons to avoid using exceptions in normal code paths.

Comment: This is a good article.  Particularly relevant in this context, I think, is the "Bonehead" exception description:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A different way is to let these pairs be represented by a class, which itself has a static factory method that will return `null` on failure.

```
public final class Pair {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public Pair(key, value) {
        // TODO: Add proper argument checking/throw exceptions.

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() [
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the string representation which looks like @{code key=value}.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

And the static factory method:

```
/**
 * Constructs a Pair from the given string,
 * returns null if the string is misformed or
 * the string was null.
 * 
 * A well formed input looks like {@code key=value} and
 * does not start with a {@code #} as that indicates comments.
 */
public static Pair fromString(String str) {
    // We do not accept nulls and empty strings.
    if (str == null || str.empty()) {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO: Figure out if trimming of str would be a good idea.

    // Skip comments.
    if (str.startsWith("#")) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] splitted = str.split("=");

    // We also do not accept anything else.
    if (splitted.length != 2) {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO: Are you accepting zero-length keys/values?

    return new Pair(splitted[0], splitted[1]);
}
```

It basically looks the same as your loop, with two important differences:

1. It's a method of its own, easily reusable, easily testable.
2. It has documentation what the input should look like.

Now to your loop:

```
for (String line : lines) {
    Pair pair = Pair.fromString(line);
    if (pair != null && !values.containsKey(pair.getKey())) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

That does not only shorten the code inside the loop, but will in the end make it more readable because you're now using `pair.getValue()` instead of `pair[1]`.

Based on the context of this I would suggest other names, though, like `StringPair`, `Setting`, `SettingsPair` or `ConfigEntry`.

Here is your loop with the log statements (assuming that the LOGGER has an overload that works similar to `Logger.log(...)`):

```
for (String line : lines) {
    Pair pair = Pair.fromString(line);
    if (pair != null) {
        if (!values.containsKey(pair.getKey()) {
            // TODO
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Pair is already assigned: {0}", pair);
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Skipping line: {0}", line);
    }
}
```

There are no fine-grained error messages there because it should be obvious from the input why the `fromString` function could not create the `Pair`.

Though we're back at two `if`-statemens with `else` branches, readability is a lot better.

---

This does violate Item 43 from Effective Java (2nd Edition) which goes like this:

> Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls

But why did I than suggest this approach? Effective Java states that it is better to throw fine grained exceptions rather then return `null` to ease dealing with the method. This is true for any sort of method, but it is not what this approach is supposed to do. We *don't care* what kind of problem there is, we just want an object that is usable for our program logic or move on, discarding fine grained errors in the process.

If you use this approach you need to keep some things in mind:

- Don't use a constructor for this purpose but a static factory method.
- Document the behavior and purpose of the static factory method thoroughly.
- It should be obvious when seeing the input what the function returns.
- Know when to use this and when to use exception handling (be aware why this is not a generic all-in-one solution to everything).
- If this is inside a library/public API, always provide a way that does throw fine grained exceptions.

---

In case you're parsing ini or settings file with this which do not require "special" treatment, [the answer from AJMansfield is correct](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40179/2612).

> Do not roll your own version if `java.util.Properties` works for it.

Comment: I would either call it `StringPair` or `Pair<String,String>`.

Comment: The fromString method won't look quite as clean if the LOGGER statements are re-inserted. There's a loss of functionality here.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: I do not consider Logger statements "functionality", I also fail to see the need to reinsert *all* of these statements. In my opinion it should be obvious why the function returned what it returned by looking at the input. If it is not-obvious from looking at the input, then there's something wrong with the function. You could achieve something along these lines by splitting the `if` condition and utilizing the `else` parts. That way you get logging but without the need for finer grained messages (it's either: "Yo, this is malformed" or "Already exists").

Comment: @Bobby I guess just as a matter of lines, if you want to log the message, now you have to test after getting the `NULL`—it doesn’t come out as short.

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps you could even replace the static factory method by a Parser class.

Comment: Please, please don't use `null` to signify invalid lines. Either throw `IllegalArgumentException` or use Guava's / SE8's [Optional<T>](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) . The OP doesn't specify what the file looks like, but `null` is really not the thing for this.

Comment: @TC1: Normally I'd agree with you, but I consider this one of the "edge" cases where this is quite valid. You're right that the constructor should have proper argument checking and should throw exceptions, but the `fromString` method is explicitly designed for this and, most importantly, it's documented that it does return `null`.

Comment: There are however some issues with this code: 1. As other's mentioned, `null` is a bad way to signal validation errors. 2. `Pair.fromString` does both parsing and validation. By returning `null` you lose the information about the validation error (i.e. the `"malformed line"` message). So the code is functionally different, regardless of whether you think that this information is unimportant. 3. You didn't actually answer OP's question. Well, implicitly you did, because you chose nested `if`, but guard statements are IMHO more readable (i.e. simply writing `if (pair == null) continue;`).

Comment: @Groo: 200_success and rolfl did answer the question, I provided a different way, so did AJMansField (most likely even a better one). I don't necessarily see a problem with that, as I said before, I consider showing (sometimes completely) different ways an important part of reviewing code.

Answer (score 51):

Your first excerpt is fine, and it is better than your second.  Your second excerpt is worse because of the deeper nesting.  (Also, if you were to choose nesting anyway, I'd invert the conditions to put the shorter code branch first to reduce mental workload when reading the code.)

Consider *why* the [`goto` statement is considered harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF).  Since it has the potential to jump to arbitrary places in the code, it could turn your program into a pile of spaghetti.

The use of `continue` is not a problem.  You still have a structured loop, and the only thing it can do is proceed to the top of the loop to process the next element (if there is one).  No chance of spaghetti there.

If you don't care about logging, you could use a capturing regular expression, which takes care of your first two conditions as well as trimming whitespace.  You would only have to worry about whether the key already exists.

Comment: To be fair, `continue` can be used to jump somewhat arbitrarily around if the [labeled version](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ContinueWithLabelDemo.htm) is used.  It's not always quite as straightforward.

Comment: I'm not sure why you object so strongly to `continue`.  I'd be curious to see what arguments you come up with for a "`continue` statement considered harmful" essay.

Comment: I don't object so strongly to it, and I don't think it's horribly harmful.  I just think that unless the `continue` conditions are all listed nicely and neatly at the top of a method (rather than scattered throughout as demonstrated) that is really damages someone's ability to follow through code intuitively.  That's all.  Basically what I said in the question.  The question isn't about whether one is more harmful to a program than the other (since both work just fine), just what's a better practice for readability/maintainability and so on.

Comment: @JeffGohlke - Everything I've ever seen about `continue`/`break` has only said that the labeled version should be avoided.  Avoiding the unlabeled form inside a loop is like avoiding `return` statements.

Comment: @Bobson I agree with the analogy completely.  The question could be restructured to ask about having lots of `return` statements ("return early, return often") or having lots of nested conditions and fewer `return`s.  Same idea.

Comment: @Bobson: Wow. I religiously avoid the unlabelled version, because the only way to know where it goes it by poking through layers of code, and as people we're pretty bad about that.  An explicit label on the construct of interest avoids that completely. It also avoids the "inserting a loop inside another shuts down the electric grid of the entire East coast", a rather famous software bug involving a break... without a label.

Comment: @IraBaxter - If your code is complex enough that you can't tell you're in a loop, then you really need to refactor it.  And since the unlabeled versions only apply to the current loop, it *should* be trivial to tell where they go.

Comment: @Bobson: say what you like; the east coast disaster was real and traceable directly to "don't use labels".

Comment: @IraBaxter - Got a link to source that?  I can't find anything on google, but I'm not sure what terms to use.

Comment: @IraBaxter - I would be interested to see that too.

Comment: _Expert C Programming_ by Peter van der Linden mentions it; apparently the AT&T programmer wanted to exit an if block, and the break exited the surrounding block, meaning a struct didn't get initialized. A watchdog program detected this and restarted the system; the system when restarted sent out a packet to the other systems ... that triggered this bug and crashed them. It was the phone system, not the electric grid. http://www.mit.edu/hacker/part1.html calls it the Martin Luther King Day Crash, though it doesn't go into detail.

Comment: Electric grid disaster of east coast sounds like [the 2003 incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_blackout_of_2003) to me, where [a race condition caused problems](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2004/04/08/blackout_bug_report/). "There was a couple of processes that were in contention for a common data structure, and through a software coding error in one of the application processes, they were both able to get write access to a data structure at the same time," "And that corruption lead to the alarm event application getting into an infinite loop and spinning."" Maybe a mixup.

Comment: I think @prosifaes has identified the one I was thinking of. Yes, phone system not electrical grid for that specific case but it doesn't surprise that there were other massive failures cause by similar coding glitches.   If you want to read about more disasters caused by stupid code errors (some of this type), go read the Peter Nuemann's Risks summary in "Software Engineering News" going back for decades.  My original comment stands: if a loop break uses explicit labels, nobody has to guess where they go, and they won't suddenly surprise you when a new layer of goo gets inserted into the code.

Answer (score 25):

I find it strange that the zero-length line problem has not yet been pointed out:

```
for(String line : lines) {

     if(line.charAt(0) == '#') {
         ....
```

The code above assumes a non-empty line in all cases, [otherwise you get IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

This is the sort of issue that should be identified and covered with Unit testing.

This also leads on to the fact that you appear to be [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), and should consider the suggestion for using [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Despite that suggestion, I have to weigh in on the `continue`/`break` theoretical discussion as well. Loop entry and exit points are already the targets of branch instructions in the compiled (JIT or Byte) code that Java produces. These branch points are well managed, and have clean, and well documented entry/exit conditions. They are nothing like the concept of a GOTO. I have, over time, become very comfortable with using them, and they are no more distrustful than an early-return from a method call. In fact, conceptually, that is what they are, simply an early-termination of a block of code that happens to be in a loop, and the termination may allow (`continue`) or disallow (`break`) further iteration.

I would not recommend using these statements with impunity, but, the fact that `break` is the natural syntax in the `switch` statement gives some hint that it's OK to use. It is the right tool for some jobs. Use it when appropriate.

Answer (score 24):

Your problem is not with the loop construct - nor is it with GOTOs. Your problem is you are avoiding some tools that can make your code better.

Here's an example.

```
enum Validator {
    IsNotComment("Skipping commented line in file.") {

        @Override
        boolean isValid(String s) {
            return !s.startsWith("#");
        }

    },
    IsAPair("Not a pair") {

        @Override
        boolean isValid(String s) {
            return s.trim().split("=").length == 2;
        }

    };

    abstract boolean isValid(String s);

    public final String failMsg;

    Validator(String failMsg) {
        this.failMsg = failMsg;
    }
}

public void test() {
    String[] lines = {"Hello"};
    Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        boolean valid = true;
        String failMsg = "";
        for ( Validator v : Validator.values() ) {
            valid &= v.isValid(line);
            if ( !valid ) {
                failMsg = v.failMsg;
            }
        }
        if ( valid ) {
            // Do stuff with valid lines.
            String [] parts = line.trim().split("=");
            values.add(parts[0],parts[1]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed validation: "+failMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

See that by refactoring properly you can now add more validations steps without affecting the main code, each one will only add to the quality. You have now transformed brittle code that is comparably difficult to understand and enhance into something clear and flexible.

This encourages you to focus on the fact that you are trying to mix validation with parsing.

If you let your worries guide you properly you will see that the validation is a separate process and your attempt to mix the validation into the parsing process is making your code smell.

Validate first - then parse. Do **not** pre-optimise and merge them into one until you have a good *measured* reason to do so - and even then measure again.

### Added

Just for the joy of it - here's what it might look like in Java 8

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
        "# Comment",
        "",
        "A=B",
        "A=C",
        "X=Y ",
        "P = Q");

public void test() {
    Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<>();
    lines.stream()
            // Trim it and lowercase.
            .map(s -> s.trim().toLowerCase())
            // Discard empty lines - good call @rolfl
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            // Discard comments.
            .filter(s -> s.charAt(0) != '#')
            // Split the trimmed form
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            // Must be two parts.
            .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
            // Trim each one.
            .map(a -> new String[]{a[0].trim(), a[1].trim()})
            // Not seen already.
            .filter(a -> !values.containsKey(a[0]))
            // Install in values.
            .forEach (a -> values.put(a[0], a[1]));
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

This really actually prints:

```
{p=q, a=b, x=y}
```

Now is that cool or what?

Sorry but it doesn't do all your helpful printing and stuff.

Comment: Thank you for this post.  This really gave me an epiphany moment concerning the code.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The problem with this approach is you separate validation and processing. Which would lead to code duplication. e.g. `// Do stuff with valid lines.` would also contain a `String.split("=")`.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca - That miniscule loss is balanced by a significant gain in code quality. It also suggests that you should use a new class to handle the String so you can retain the parts.

Comment: Good call on the Java8 streams .... looks interesting. And thanks for the 'good call' as well. You will probably find that this `.filter(s -> s.length() > 0)` is better written as `.filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())`... Nice Answer! (good thing you edited. I have votes now!)

Comment: @rolfl - Thanks (again) for the useful feedback. `isEmpty` deployed.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `failMsg += v.failMsg`, since the code as written overwrites an existing `failMsg` in case of multiple errors. If only the first message should be printed, why not break out of the validation loop immediately? I like the enum setup—one way of addressing @abuzittingillifirca comment on efficiency is you can split the validators (two implementations of an interface) into pre-parse and post-parse. In this example, the inefficiency is probably trivial, but not if the simple `split` were something expensive.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Least of my problems with **code duplication** is efficiency.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Yes, I don't like the duplicated parsing, either. I do like the Validator class, though.

Comment: Couldn't you actually reimplement the Logger-Messages inside the filter conditions? like ( a == 2 || LogAndReturnFalse(...)) ?

Comment: @Falco - Forgive the delay in responding. No, that would force all users of the Validator to suffer log entries. I would much rather make the error message available for use than force the user to deal with logging side effects. Maybe the error message should be a `List<String>` but no more. Good intent but wrong approach.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't write directly to the system logger, but collecting all errors in a list and logging them afterwards would provide all functionality of the original question!

Answer (score 19):

Here is a far and away superior solution: use [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to handle your configuration file.  `Properties` supports a [`key=value` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) that is very similar to the one you are trying to parse.  It's up to you to decide whether that syntax is close enough to handle any existing configuration files you might have, and whether the validation and logging in your current code are essential.

Comment: Even though the question is more about code style, this is a case of where the question can be "X or Y?" and the answer is "Z!". A reminder to always think outside the box. +1 for the edited version of this answer.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with @200_sucess that the first version is better.

An alternative may be a subroutine:

```
for(String line : lines) {
    AddLine(line, values);
    //...and so on with still more processing
}

void AddLine(String line, Map<String, String> values)
{
    if(line.charAt(0) == '#') {
        LOGGER.debug("Skipping commented line in file.");
        return;
    }

    line = line.trim().toLowerCase();
    String[] pair = line.split("=");

    if(pair.length != 2) {
        LOGGER.error("Skipping malformed line in file: " + line);
        return;
    }

    pair[0] = pair[0].trim();
    pair[1] = pair[1].trim();

    if(values.containsKey(pair[0])) {
        LOGGER.debug("Value is already assigned.");
        return;
    }

    values.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
}
```

Do you mind the "early return" in a subroutine? Would you goto the end of the subroutine in order to return, or build a deeply-nested if?

Answer (score 9):

Here's an answer out of left-field, but it may give you some inspiration.  If I were doing this in Haskell I would write it as a pipeline of maps and folds on a list.  I don't know much about Java, but could you rewrite your function as several smaller functions each of which acts on an iterator and produces a new iterator to feed into the next function?

```
processLines = insertInto dict
              . map trimPairs
              . filter notMalformed
              . map splitLine
              . filter notComment
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest a functional approach too. The problem is basically passing some input through a series of filters, which is modeled perfectly in a functional way.

Comment: This is also a very good idea.  Thank you.  I might actually end up going with this.

Comment: Java 8 can help here :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Can you explain?  My production environment is just getting Java 7 this year, so I'm still busy trying to master things like lambda and try-with-resources blocks.  Haha

Comment: @JeffGohlke Java 8 introduced Streams and some other utilities, like Files.lines(path) that returns a Stream. Map and filter are applied on streams. You can then map every line to something(even a bean), then you can filter them on the fly.

Comment: See my Java 8 implementation [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40220/11913).

Answer (score 7):

Let me echo @AJMasfield that for this particular example **Don't Reinvent the Wheel.** However, this question comes up in contexts other than Properties. In the second version, the LOGGER messages are further and further away from the relevant `if` clauses. The first version uses an idiom we should be familiar with, checking preconditions and error exits up at the top. I find it quite readable.

Answer (score 6):

**The solution to your problem (given in the example):**

1. Select the contents of your `for` block
2. Refactor -> Extract method
3. Inspect program to make sure nothing broke
4. Inspect the new generated method to see if it's ugly
5. If ugly, select ugly parts, go to #2
6. If you can't select them because they are too scattered in the body, rearrange until you can
7. If you can't rearrange because code would break, reconsider your algorithm design - does it really have to be this convoluted?
8. If yes, accept it and move on. Not all code can be beautiful, and sometimes perfectionism isn't worth it.

---

**The answer to your question (example aside):**

`goto` is very rarely needed in modern languages. Part of the reason is that things like `return`, `break`, `continue` and `throw` exist. These are basically very limited versions of `goto` that are incapable of causing anywhere near as much chaos, but can still satisfy a popular `goto` use case. It is unlikely that you will encounter `goto` worthy code which cannot be tamed using these tools and applying some intelligent refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others that the first one is better because it's easier to read but *@AJMansfield* also has a really good point. It's worth mentioning that you can also use Guava's [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) and [`MapSplitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html) classes or write something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the notion "ask forgiveness rather than permission", I would put the line handling in a try-catch block, like so :

```
for(String line : lines) {

    try {
        if(line.charAt(0) == '#') {
            throw new Exception("Skipping commented line in file.");
        }

        line = line.trim().toLowerCase();
        String[] pair = line.split("=");

        pair[0] = pair[0].trim();
        pair[1] = pair[1].trim();

        if(values.containsKey(pair[0])) {
            throw new Exception("Value is already assigned.");
        }

        values.put(pair[0], pair[1]);

        //...and so on with still more processing
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Skipping line in file: " + line + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This can catch any other case you may not have considered, such as the line being null or empty, or any thing else in the line processing.

I would probably extract a method to include the `values.put` with the `containsKey` test that would throw the exception. Any kind of test you need to perform can be extracted to a method that throws an exception if the condition is not met, such as

```
public void testComment(String line) throws Exception {
    if (line.charAt(0)) {
        throw new Exception("Skipping commented line in file.");
    }
}
```

To conclude, I think exceptions work in this case because you expect a specific input, and anything that does not match it (any exception to it) it to be discarded.

Comment: A comment is too routine to justify the use of an exception. The variable-already-assigned situation might be handled that way. Still, catching _all_ `Exception`s makes me uneasy. To trace the intended flow, I have to examine _every single function call_ in the `try` block and brainstorm ideas about what kinds of exceptions might be thrown. It reminds me of [this code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37244/9357).